# Al darle a guardar y guardar como se cierra el programa PyQt5 (modificado)

Tags: python, pyqt5, menú, guardar

Soy nuevo en esto de Python y me ha surgido un problema y es que si no he seleccionado ningún archivo y le doy a los botones del menú 'Guardar archivo' y 'Guardar como' el programa se cierra yo pretendo hacer que si le doy y no hay ningún archivo seleccionado me salte una advertencia diciendo 'Porfavor adjunte un archivo', he probado muchas cosas pero no consigo dar con ninguna solución.

He cambiado y acortado un poco el código dada la recomendación en los comentarios. Y no he podido conseguir lo que se me ha recomendado de intentar cambiar la condicional en el if, en el código que muestro he intentado que si nombre == "" dado que si no se le da ningún valor no te dará la opción de elegir archivo.

Os dejo aquí una porción de mi código, para llegar al estado en el que no hay ningún archivo seleccionado nada más salir la ventana que te pide el nombre de trabajador hay que darle a Cancel.

```
import sys
import csv
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QDialog, QLabel, QComboBox, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Establecer el título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle("Comprobación cableado")
        # Crea un QTableWidget para mostrar los datos
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)
    
        # Crea una barra de menú con la opción "Guardar archivo"
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Guardar')
        saveFile = fileMenu.addAction('Guardar archivo')
        saveFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+G')
        saveFile.triggered.connect(self.saveDialog)
        
        # Crea una acción para guardar como
        saveAsFile = fileMenu.addAction('Guardar como')
        saveAsFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+Shift+S')
        saveAsFile.triggered.connect(self.saveAsDialog)
        
        self.info()
        # Maximizar la ventana principal
        self.showMaximized()
        # Hacer que la ventana se abra en primer plano
        self.activateWindow()

    def info(self):
        
        # Pedir al usuario el nombre del trabajador
        nombre = ""
        while nombre == "":
            
            nombre, ok1 = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Nombre de trabajador', 'Ingrese el nombre de trabajador:', flags=Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
            if not ok1:
                return  # Agregado para parar la función en caso de darle a cancelar
            elif nombre == "":
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Advertencia", "Por favor, ingrese el nombre del trabajador.")
                
        ruta_base = None
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
            if nombre in dirs:
                ruta_base = os.path.join(root, nombre)
                break
                
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ruta_base = ruta_base
        # Muestra la ventana de exploración y obtiene la ruta del archivo seleccionado
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Abrir archivo', self.ruta_base, 'CSV (*.csv)')[0]
    def saveDialog(self):
        # Obtener los valores ingresados por el usuario
        nombre = self.nombre
        if nombre =="":
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Advertencia", "Por favor, seleccione un archivo.")
                
        else:
            # Obtener el nombre del archivo seleccionado
            fname = self.tableWidget.property("filename")
            # Guarda el nombre del archivo seleccionado en una propiedad de la tabla
        self.tableWidget.setProperty("filename", fname)
    def saveAsDialog(self):
        # Obtener los valores ingresados por el usuario
        nombre = self.nombre
        if nombre =="":
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Advertencia", "Por favor, seleccione un archivo.")
            return
        else:
            # Obtener el nombre del archivo seleccionado
            fname = self.tableWidget.property("filename")

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hola, tu código tiene 300 líneas. Considero que tendrías mejor chance de recibir una respuesta si lo reduces a un [mcve]. Un saludo y bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Comment: Hola Ioritz, bienvenido, yo pondría un **print( filaName )** debajo de **if fileName** (en el método **saveAsDialog**), probablemente, te de la sorpresa de que nunca es **null** por lo que deberás cambiar la condición de if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido solucionar mi problema englobando toda la función en un 'try-except' no se si es la mejor solución posible, si alguien encuentra o sabe alguna mejor hacermelo saber gracias.

Aqui mi solución:

```
try:
except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Se ha producido un error al intentar guardar el archivo: {str(e)}")
```